# ARM GCC cross compiler, decimal float, unable to emulate 'SD/DD/TD'

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, decimal-point

I would like to ask a question about GCC cross compiler for ARM architecture and about decimal floating point numbers based on the ISO/IEC TR 24732 standard,  which is implemented in a `<decimal/decimal>` library.

I compiled a GCC cross compiler for ARM by using crosstool-ng with enabled decimal float support by using flag `--enable-decimal-float=yes`. All went OK.

But when I try to compile a test application for my target (arm1176jzf-s), then I`ve got errors, such as:

```
unable to emulate 'SD'
unable to emulate 'DD'
unable to emulate 'TD'
```

There is sample of output from compiler:

```
    /home/pajano/x-tools/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.9.4/decimal/decimal:230:56: error: unable to emulate 'SD'
         typedef float __decfloat32 __attribute__((mode(SD)));
                                                            ^
    /home/pajano/x-tools/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.9.4/decimal/decimal:251:5: error: 'std::decimal::decimal32::decimal32(std::decimal::decimal32::__decfloat32)' cannot be overloaded
         decimal32(__decfloat32 __z)   : __val(__z) {}
         ^
    /home/pajano/x-tools/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.9.4/decimal/decimal:238:14: error: with 'std::decimal::decimal32::decimal32(float)'
         explicit decimal32(float __r)  : __val(__r) {}
                  ^
    /home/pajano/x-tools/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.9.4/decimal/decimal:316:56: error: unable to emulate 'DD'
         typedef float __decfloat64 __attribute__((mode(DD)));
                                                            ^
    /home/pajano/x-tools/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.9.4/decimal/decimal:337:5: error: 'std::decimal::decimal64::decimal64(std::decimal::decimal64::__decfloat64)' cannot be overloaded
         decimal64(__decfloat64 __z)   : __val(__z) {}
         ^
    /home/pajano/x-tools/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.9.4/decimal/decimal:324:14: error: with 'std::decimal::decimal64::decimal64(float)'
         explicit decimal64(float __r)  : __val(__r) {}
                  ^
    /home/pajano/x-tools/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/arm-linaro-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.9.4/decimal/decimal:402:57: error: unable to emulate 'TD'
         typedef float __decfloat128 __attribute__((mode(TD)));
                                                             ^
...
```

This is simple test application which I am using, for test. On x86 arch. this application compiles without any problem:

```
#include <stdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <decimal/decimal>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    decimal::decimal32 total;
    decimal::decimal32 nom = decimal::decimal32(0.1);
    int quantity = 10;
    total = decimal::decimal32(nom*quantity);
    return 0;
}
```

So if is here anyone who can help to get rid of these errors, I will be glad for any help.

Comment: TBH, decimal floating point is an ultra-niche feature. Even in finance,it's not that important (use decimal _fixed_ point). On ARM, decimal floating point is plain weird.

Comment: [_"Not all targets support decimal floating types."_](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html) - that's probably about all there is to say...